# How to call a javascript function after the angularjs has finished loading and page is rendered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**Background**:

I have an angularjs application which displays a datetimepicker field.

**Issue**:

Once the page is loaded I want to run a javascript function to initialize the datepicker used in the page. 
At the moment it seems that the function call that I placed at the end of the page doesn't get picked.

Note : 
I use the 'bootstrap datetimepicker' from (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: which datepicker you are using?

Comment: in the `controller` you can reinitialized but not a good practice.

Comment: I use the bootstrap datetimepicker

Comment: use `angular bootstrap` as it's very easy to configure http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 2):

Just use the $viewContentLoaded event

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    //call it here
    yourFunction();
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this code should be placed into a directive and not called from a controller or a service \  etc. As the intent is to do DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know when Angular is done is from inside Angular. You should wrap the code that initalizes the date picker into a directive, add binding as needed, and in a $timeout function do the JS initialization.